# Google OAuth: how to exchange serverAuthCode from Flutter / GoogleSignIn on backend?

Tags: flutter, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

i try to fetch a refreshToken from an authCode on a backend (testing with Postman for now);  coming from a Flutter (mobile) app without any luck so far :(

What I tried so far:

GoogleCloud side:

- creating an OAuth web(!) client, so it has clientId and clientSecret; no redirectUri-s specified

on Flutter side:

```
GoogleSignIn(
    serverClientId: <the clientId of the OAuth web client from above>
    forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    scopes: [
      CalendarApi.calendarReadonlyScope,
      CalendarApi.calendarEventsReadonlyScope,
    ],
  );
```

on Postman/NodeJS side:

```
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token  
query params:
 * code=<serverAuthCode I got from GoogleSignIn>
 * client_id=<the same Google OAuth client id I use in GoogleSignIn>
 * client_secret=<corresponding client secret>
 * redirect_uri=<empty string>
 * grant_type=authorization_code
```

I always get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

What do I miss? :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, nevermind..

..i am just kidding, here is the trick :D

Contrary to the GoogleSignIn documentation, I had to set the clientId and NOT the serverClientId..

so it looks like this now:

```
GoogleSignIn(
    **clientId**: <the clientId of the OAuth web client from above>
    forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    scopes: [
      CalendarApi.calendarReadonlyScope,
      CalendarApi.calendarEventsReadonlyScope,
    ],
  );
```